# How to POST multiple files in one Request using VolleyMutlipart in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function that takes file name and its Uri then send that file to the server.

**Here it is**

```
private fun uploadFile(pdfname: String, anyfile: Uri) {

        var iStream: InputStream? = null
        val myurl = "https://apiurl"
        var rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        try {
            iStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(anyfile)
            val inputData = getBytes(iStream)
            val volleyMultipartRequest: VolleyMultipartRequest = object : VolleyMultipartRequest(
                Method.POST, myurl,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    try {
                        val jsonobject = JSONObject(String(response.data))
                        val returnmsg = jsonobject.getString("hua ki nhi")
                        if(returnmsg == "aish kro ho gya")
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "File Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        dialog.cancel()
                    }catch (e: JSONException){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        dialog.cancel()
                    }
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        error.message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    dialog.cancel()
                }) {
                
                @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
//                override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>? {
//                    // params.put("tags", "ccccc");  add string parameters
//                    return HashMap()
//                }

               
                override fun getByteData(): Map<String, DataPart> {
                    val params: MutableMap<String, DataPart> = HashMap()
                    params["evidence_image"] = DataPart(pdfname, inputData)
                    return params
                }
            }
            volleyMultipartRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
            )
            rQueue.add(volleyMultipartRequest)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun getBytes(inputStream: InputStream?): ByteArray {
        val byteBuffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val bufferSize = 1024
        val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
        var len = 0
        while (inputStream!!.read(buffer).also { len = it } != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len)
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray()
    }
```

But I have to pass the Uri 1 by 1 to upload to the server. That means I have to call for API every time to upload multiple files.

This is my code where I take multiple files from the user.

```
attachbtn.setOnClickListener {
    val mimeTypes = arrayOf("image/*", "application/pdf")
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/* | application/pdf"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Picture"), 111)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data?.clipData != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Multiple file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val mulfile = data.clipData!!
            val itemcount = mulfile.itemCount
        }
    }
}
```

I have already Included VolleyMultipartRequest Class.

Please tell me a Way where I can send Multiple Files in one Request.
Thankyou.

Comment: params["evidence_image1"] = DataPart(pdfname1, inputData1)
                    params["evidence_image2"] = DataPart(pdfname2,  inputData2)
                     params["evidence_image3"] = DataPart(pdfname3, inputData3)
                    return params

Comment: Can I send it in a list coz I don't know how many file user will select?

Comment: You can make a loop. Yes. Use a list first and then add them from list. BUT first... select three files and do all hard coded. It was just a suggestion so try it out in a simple way first. I do not know if it would work. Try. Start with two.